# Why write uint256 instead of uint if they're the same thing?

Tags: solidity, data-types, uint256

Is `uint` the same as `uint256` in Solidity?

If this is the case, then why do a lot smart contracts make extensive use of `uint256` and not just write `uint` instead? Is this merely to be explicit?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, they are exact aliases.

Some developers (including me) prefer to use `uint256` because it is consistent with other `uint` data types, which also specify their size, and also because making the size of the data explicit reminds the developer and the reader how much data they've got to play with, which may help prevent or detect bugs.

Some other languages have left out the bare `uint` version for just these reasons. For example, Bamboo only has `uint256`.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what @EdmundEdgar said, it's also better to be explicit when constructing method signature ID's.

For example if doing `bytes4(keccak('transfer(address, uint)'))`, you'll get a different method sig ID than `bytes4(keccak('transfer(address, uint256)'))` and smart contracts will only understand the latter when comparing method sig IDs.

Comment: Don't be so self demeaning, your answer is superior.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say RTFM, but this one was too trivial.  "uint and int are aliases for uint256 and int256, respectively." --https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#value-types

Comment: Thanks. I was actually reading that exact page and missed it unfortunately. But in any case, I assumed they were the same, but am still unclear why people use `uint256` instead of `uint` in contracts? I see this a lot and it seems unnecessary

Comment: When I googled it, I came across a hit for an app that was changing all instances of uint to uint256.  I'm guessing the reason is to avoid incompatibility if, at some point in the future, the meaning of uint changes to uint512 or something.  Much like C and "long" v "long long" v "int" or "short".

Comment: PS.  I've been using uint, myself ...

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock people use `uint256` either to be explicit with their code in case of any changes to the alias of `uint` and it's visually easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to use `uint256`. It brings about readability and consistency in your code, and it allows you to adhere to best practices in smart contracts.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave something related in case you want to see another example of the consequences of using uint.

https://medium.com/@mattaereal/jackpot-or-honeypot-a-quick-lesson-on-solcs-uint-and-function-selectors-cc1ea7f6afce